# C++ why raw pointer won't increase reference count of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

the `shared_ptr` use reference count to determine when to destroy the object. 
And pls look at this code:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> pt = std::make_shared<int>(3);
    int *pt2 = pt.get();
    cout << "reference count " << pt.use_count() << endl;
    pt = 0;
    cout << *pt2;

};
```

after I set pt to 0, the reference count should become 0, and the object should be destroyed. But I can still use pt2 to access it. In my case, the result is correct, but I guess it's just luck. So does it mean that the reference count mechanism still can not make it 100% safe if the programmer want to do some stupid thing?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is quite right. It's C++ : you can still shoot yourself in the foot :)

Comment: "Smart pointers" aren't pointers, aren't smart, and aren't a fix for incompetence wit pointers. They merely help with automatic release of resources at end of scope

Comment: If the reference count became 0 the object would/should be lost on access through raw pointer, I am glad it isn't like that!

Comment: The library type only implements the boiler-plate one would need to manage it correctly. It doesn't protect against mismanagement. Nothing can protect against the human factor in programming.

Comment: @StoryTeller Some languages do protect against many aspects of the human factor, I'm thinking of Haskell for example.

Comment: @OlivierSohn - Funny you felt the need to qualify it with "many", and not "all", eh? ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't say "all" because you can write bugs in Haskell, too :) but many bugs you could write in C++ are caught by the Haskell compiler / type system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> after I set pt to 0, the reference count should become 0, and the object should be destroyed

The reference count did become zero and the object was destroyed.

Replace `int` with your own class `MyInt` to see the constructors and destructors being called...

```
class MyInt
{
private:
   int val;

public:
   MyInt() : val(0)          { std::cout << "default c'tor called" << std::endl; }
   MyInt(int rhs) : val(rhs) { std::cout << "c'tor (" << rhs << ") called" << std::endl; }
   ~MyInt()                  { std::cout << "d'tor called" << std::endl; }
   int getval (void)         { return val; }
};
```

… then update `main()` …

```
int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<MyInt> pt = std::make_shared<MyInt>(3);

   MyInt* pt2 = pt.get();

   std::cout << "reference count " << pt.use_count() << std::endl;

   pt = 0;

   std::cout << pt2->getval() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The output will (perhaps) look like this...

> c'tor (3) called
>   reference count 1
>   d'tor called
>   3

[runnable sample](https://www.ideone.com/jR36E4)

The fact that the last line of output is the value three (**if** it *is* three) is not evidence that the object was not deleted.

Dereferencing a pointer that points to a deleted object is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) so anything can happen.

Answer (score 5):

That is not how `shared_ptr` works. 
The count increments when you generate a new shared pointer from the first one. `get` is just a method to deal with legacy code that can only take a raw pointer.
By using `get` you are subverting the safety of the smart pointer.

In other words, a pointer from `get` is only good as an observer, not as an owner and for when you really need a raw pointer. 
If you just need an observer use `weak_ptr`.

It is true that in principle `get` could increment the count assuming ownership, but still it wouldn't be clear when to decrement it again. 
Once the raw pointer is extracted there is no way to get back to the counter of the original.

Stay away from using `get` unless you know what you are doing.

This is how it works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main(){

    std::shared_ptr<int> pt = std::make_shared<int>(3);
    assert(pt.use_count() == 1);
    std::shared_ptr<int> pt2 = pt;
    assert(pt.use_count() == 2);
    assert(pt2.use_count() == 2);
    pt.reset(); // or pt = 0;
    assert(pt.use_count() == 0);
    assert(pt2.use_count() == 1);
    assert(*pt2 == 3);
    assert(!pt);

    return 0;
}
```